# Install Scrapy in apache airflow will cause INVALID_ARGUMENT

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scrapy, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I`m trying to install **Scrapy** from PyPi using below command.

```
gcloud composer environments update $(AIRFLOW_ENVIRONMENT_NAME) \
    --update-pypi-packages-from-file requirements.txt \
    --location $(AIRFLOW_LOCATION)
```

requirements.txt is like this.

```
google-api-python-client==1.7.*
google-cloud-datastore==1.7.*
Scrapy==2.0.0
```

After running gcloud command, It will cause an invalid argument but it runs successfully in the local environment.

```sh
gcloud composer environments update xxxx \
        --update-pypi-packages-from-file requirements.txt \
        --location asia-northeast1
ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.update) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Found 1 problem:
        1) Error validating key Scrapy. PyPi dependency name is not formatted properly. It must be lowercase and follow the format of 'identifier' specified in PEP-508.
```

Is there any way to install?

Comment: Can you share your GCP composer image version?

Comment: @mk_sta Thank you. I am using `apache-airflow==1.10.9`

Answer (score 2):

As the previous answer stated, the error that you are receiving now is quite clear and it's caused by the wrong formatting of the dependency. It should be `scrapy==2.0.0` instead of `Scrapy==2.0.0` inside the `requirements.txt`.

I would like to add that to avoid the installation error when you fix the formatting, you should add one more dependency to your list and that is `attrs==19.2.0`. I was able to install your requirements to my environment by specifying the following list:

```
google-api-python-client==1.7.*
google-cloud-datastore==1.7.*
scrapy==2.0.0
attrs==19.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you adjust package name in `requirements.txt` file according to [PEP-508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#grammar) document prerequisites, formatting certan package name in lowercase layout `scrapy==2.0.0`, the issue most probably will remain the same and updating process will stuck with the error:

> Failed to install PyPI packages

Generally, this kind of error appears then the source PyPI package has some external dependencies or this package is sensitive on some system-level libraries that GCP Composer doesn't support.

In this case a vendor recommends two ways either using [KubernetesPodOperator](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator) to build own custom image and use it in particular Kubernetes Pod or deploy PyPi package as a [local Python library](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-local), uploading shared object libraries for the PyPI dependency to Airflow `/plugins` directory, find more info [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#using_python_packages_that_depend_on_shared_object_libraries).